# What is the use of the character @ in @opendir in WordPress

Tags: php

I would like to know the use of `@` character in WordPress. For example:

`if ( $plugins_dir = @ opendir( WP_CONTENT_DIR ) ) { ... }`

Also what is the difference between `@opendir` and `@ opendir`, i.e. using a space after `@` character.

I am new to WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a part of the PHP language syntax and not strictly part of WordPress itself. The `@` symbol denotes that any errors from that function should be suppressed in case it fails for some reason.

This is called an [Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and you can find more information about it on the PHP documentation website. It stops errors of all types from being displayed (*which can be a good or bad thing depending on what is happening*).

There doesn't seem to be any difference between having a space and not having one. It will just depend on your style of writing code.

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.
>
> ```
> <?php
> /* Intentional file error */
> $my_file = @file ('non_existent_file') or
>     die ("Failed opening file: error was '$php_errormsg'");
>
> // this works for any expression, not just functions:
> $value = @$cache[$key];
> // will not issue a notice if the index $key doesn't exist.
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Suppressing the error reporting is always a bad thing. It provides the developer a false sense of security and correctness while their code can fail spectacularly without them being informed.

Comment: @axiac That sentence is redundant, the post is already about [tag:wordpress]. 